# calling a function in the exception class from catch block is not printing a value that is passed from try block

Tags: c++

I am  calling  a function what() in the exception class from catch block but in what() function is printing the garbage value as it is not assigned  any value instead of it should print the value thrown from checkusername() function  but it not doing so please help me out . here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
class BadLengthException
{
public:
int n1;
BadLengthException(int n)
 {
    n1=n;
  }
int what()
    {
    cout << n1;
    }
};
bool checkUsername(string username) {
bool isValid = true;
int n = username.length();
if(n < 5) {
    throw BadLengthException(n);
}
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    if(username[i] == 'w' && username[i+1] == 'w') {
        isValid = false;
    }
}
return isValid;
}

int main() {
int T; cin >> T;
while(T--) {
    string username;
    cin >> username;
    try {
        bool isValid = checkUsername(username);
        if(isValid) {
            cout << "Valid" << '\n';
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid" << '\n';
        }
    } catch (BadLengthException e) {
        cout << "Too short: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`what` doesn't have a `return` statement, and is therefore causing undefined behavior. I expect you meant to have `return n1` instead of `cout << n1`.